# Eclipse Target is not a JDK root. Java executable was not found

Tags: eclipse, java-8

I am trying to add jdk 1.8 to eclipse Windows -> preferences -> installed JRE. I get the following error msg:

`Eclipse Target is not a JDK root. Java executable was not found`

How to fix this issue?
[image]

Comment: Is your Workspace `c:\work`?

Comment: What is in the directory c:\work\jdk1.8.0_141 ?  It's possible this is just a JRE, not a JDK.  Also check the contents of c:\work\jdk1.8.0_141\bin . If "java" is there, but "javac" is not there, then this is definitely a JRE, not a JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using jdk from C:/programms/java.